# comparison of time in string format using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have column to store time as "H:Ia" format. eg: "10:30am".
What i want is to fetch records that are within a specific time interval (say two hours) which is also in "H:Ia" format.

Comment: Add structure of your table to the question

Comment: What type is this column? Because if it's `TIME`, than you're wrong, because MySQL doesn't store these values in format  "H:Ia", not even a string. Therefore you can use MySQL functions to manipulate (compare, add, subtract end so on) this column values. And if it's not `TIME` type, than it should be.

Comment: Add table structure and sql you tried till now pls.

Comment: the value is stored as varchar(100) eg: 10:30am

Answer (score 0):

You have convert this date format using STR_TO_DATE function.
Please refer this link [enter link description here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)